# How to fetch multiple URLs dynamically

Tags: curl

I want to fetch multiple URLs dynamically using cURL and PHP. When I try this with a single URL it works, but doesn't for multiple URLs. Please help.

I am using a form to send URLs:

```
$urls = $_POST["urls"];
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$useragent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

foreach ($urls as $url) 
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}

$html= str_get_html($str);
foreach($html->find('span.price') as $e)
    echo  $e->innertext . '<br>';
```

Comment: Could you describe what kind of problem you're seeing?

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\scrap\curll.php on line 14   for this line $urls = $_POST["urls"];

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: str in C:\wamp\www\scrap\curll.php on line 25  $html= str_get_html($str);

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\scrap\curll.php on line 26 foreach($html->find('span.infiPrice') as $e)

Comment: Hi Zong, above errors coming while iam testing please help

Comment: Can you post the code of the form you're using to call this page?

Comment: <form action="curl.php">

Comment: <input type="text" name="urls">
<input type="text" name="urls">
<input type="text" name="urls">
<input type="text" name="urls">
<input type="Submit" name="Submit">

Comment: <form action="curl.php"><input type="text" name="urls"> <input type="text" name="urls"> <input type="text" name="urls"> <input type="text" name="urls"> <input type="Submit" name="Submit"></form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your form, you have text inputs with the same name.  When it gets passed to curl.php, it's not passed as an array.  You can fix this by doing the following in your form:

```
<form action="curl.php">
    <input type="text" name="urls[]" />
    <input type="text" name="urls[]" />
    ...
</form>
```

Now, urls will be passed in as an array, and the foreach call will work normally.

Comment: Hi, i want to insert results to mysql database pls tell me how to do it.